# PHP7 cli vs php-fpm

Tags: php, php-7

I'm running php behind nginx with php-fpm and cron tasks to php binary (/usr/bin/php).

I've found an inconsistency - the same script outputs different results when I run it through php binary and through fpm.

**NOTE** This only applies to **PHP7**. On another server I've tested it with 5.6 and the result is identical.

Here's what I've found. The following script:

```
<?php
class Test {
    public function test(){
        $arr = (object) [
            'children' => []
        ];
        $arr->children[] = 1;
        return $arr;
    }
}

$o = new Test();
$o->test();
print_r( $o->test() );
```

Saved to `test.php`. When I run it through browser (php-fpm), will produce:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
)
```

But when I execute it from CLI, the result is different:

```
[root@server1 web]# php -f test.php
stdClass Object
(
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

It does not happen without the (object) casting. Also if I'll instantiate `$arr` with `new stdClass()` it will not happen.

Seems like the `$arr = (object)` is being preserved in the memory by php7's engine.

Maybe it's a configuration issue. Anyone ran into it before or can explain?

Thanks.

Comment: There were some caching problems just before PHP7 was released, Possibly related to one of them. Was due to some speed optimisations

Comment: And doing `which php` points to `/usr/bin/php`, right?

Comment: This looks like a bug, I would suggest reporting it at http://bugs.php.net

Comment: That's why you should wait for PHP 7.1 with production deployment :)

Comment: Could you please update with what PHP7 version you are running?

Comment: However @uruloke asks a good question. If you're using an RC version rather than the 7.0.0 release, this might be a bug which was already fixed.

Comment: Yep, @Andrea, looks like it was introduced in rc2, exists in gold master, and 7.1. But... only affects classes. https://3v4l.org/PJR7m

Comment: Ah, so it *is* a new bug.

Comment: @Mr.Llama that is correct (/usr/bin/php).
uruloke I'm using 7.0.0 (not RC).
MarcinOrlowski it's "semi-production", the server is used for local projects and not for the clients. You are absolutely right, I'll wait for upgrades before using it on our production servers.
I'll report it

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358900/different-output-of-exec-command-when-executed-in-browser-vs-terminal?noredirect=1#comment110287469_62358900

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in PHP 7 which had been reported and is now fixed:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71067