# Different output of exec() command when executed in browser vs. terminal

Tags: python, php

It's very weird that when executed in terminal, it does fine but not when triggered via browser. The python script executed via exec is just pushing jobs to RMQ and returns the documents/keys(jobs) pushed.
Browser doesn't show those keys pushed while in terminal it is shown. Please see the output arrays below:

When executed via browser:

```
(
    [0] => > -rerun
    [1] => > -status
    [2] => > -companies
    [3] => > -websites
    [4] => > -searchstring
    [5] => > -queue
    [6] => > -followrule
    [7] => {'command args'}
)
```

But when executed via terminal:

```
(
    [0] => > -rerun
    [1] => > -status
    [2] => > -companies
    [3] => > -websites
    [4] => > -searchstring
    [5] => > -queue
    [6] => > -followrule
    [7] => {'command args'}
    [8] => Çompany Keys: 4
    [9] => Websites Keys: 4
    [10] => Search Keys: 4
    [11] => Total No. Of Jobs: 1
    [12] => [x] Sent:_id 'doc_id'
    [13] => Rerun: ranks - 1
)
```

On the terminal, the job was pushed to RMQ but not when triggered via browser.

Edit: Added code

```
<?php
   $command = "sudo -u ronald /opt/env3/bin/python3 script.py";
   exec($command,$output,$return);

   echo "<pre>";
     print_r($output);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Terminal will execute PHP-CLI while browser (depending on config) PHP-FPM.

Comment: @MarkusZeller is there anyway browser will use PHP-CLI?

Comment: No, by intention. But you could use `exec()` or `system()` to run PHP scripts.

Comment: Yes, I'm using exec() on this one. The arrays are output of exec() command And the result differs when executed from terminal and web browser

Comment: Can you show the specific code part by updating the question?

Comment: @MarkusZeller added the php code

Comment: When running from web, the command `/opt/env3/bin/python3 script.py` is executed as user `www-data`. You could try executing this as the terminal user (let's say "ronald") with sudo like `sudo -u ronald /opt/env3/bin/python3 script.py`. User "ronald" must be in the sudoers list for that.

Comment: I did that but it's still the same result. Updated code for your reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215885/discussion-between-markus-zeller-and-ronald).